# What does "life plays tricks on him" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, differences, idioms, idiom-meaning

What does this statement mean?

> Life plays tricks on him.

Is it similar to

> He has a twisted fate.

Comment: 'Cosmic irony' is worth looking up.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the statements are idioms and have similar meanings.

*Life plays tricks on him* means that he often has to deal with unexpected events that seem to force him to make changes to his plans.

In the second idiom twisted generally means cruel or perverse.  The first idiom would seem like an understatement for someone with a twisted fate.

The first would infer the frequently encounters obstacles but can be dealt with like the loss of a job.  The second infers something much worse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this makes sense. It  means that  a lot of unexpected outcomes and occurrences happen to him/her.

In a sense, yes, it also means the same as "He/she has a twisted fate".

Comment: Oh thank you for your quick reply. By the way, what does your "In a sense" mean ?

Comment: "Twisted fate" can mean both "unexpected outcomes and occurences" and "very bad destiny", or he/she has bad things happening to them all the time. "Life plays tricks on him/her doesn't have the "bad things happening to them all the time" connotation

Comment: I've heard of "a twist of fate" to mean an unexpected outcome but not of someone having a "twisted fate". I'm not aware of fate having a definition that could lead to one fate being considered a twisted (i.e. abnormal) one.